# ssh illegal option while trying to connect to remote server

Tags: linux, ssh, remote-access, ssh-keys, terminal

trying to ssh from my macbook pro, to a remote server,

> ssh ayan@ServerIPAddress

gives the following error

```
ssh: illegal option -- ?
usage: ssh [-46AaCfGgKkMNnqsTtVvXxYy] [-B bind_interface]
           [-b bind_address] [-c cipher_spec] [-D [bind_address:]port]
           [-E log_file] [-e escape_char] [-F configfile] [-I pkcs11]
           [-i identity_file] [-J [user@]host[:port]] [-L address]
           [-l login_name] [-m mac_spec] [-O ctl_cmd] [-o option] [-p port]
           [-Q query_option] [-R address] [-S ctl_path] [-W host:port]
           [-w local_tun[:remote_tun]] destination [command [argument ...]]
```

I am unable to to locate the source of this error. I deleted the whole `~/.ssh/*` directory and infact any argument after `ssh` is throwing error. If I tried `ssh xyz@xyz.com` i.e. without any arguments starting with `-` then it asks for password, but after it doesnot connect and keeps asking for the password repetatively.

Comment: Are you **sure** that contains the login password? Normally, the help output from ssh starts with `[-46AaCfGgKkMNnqsTtVvXxYy]`, which is the list of single-letter options supported by the `ssh` command. Otherwise, that command line looks fine, unless you have an alias for the `ssh` command. Does the command `alias ssh` yield any output?

Comment: @larsks Wow, yeah you are right, it is not my password. Except that my login password also starts with 46 and I carelessly overlooked it. Now about the problem, can you post as a separate answer ? I want to look into your suggestion more in depth. thanks

Comment: I don't think that "do you have an alias for the `ssh` command?" really counts as an answer. It would be great if you could update your question with answers to my previous comment. If `alias ssh` doesn't show anything, then maybe also throw in the output of `type -a ssh`.

Comment: `type -a ssh` -> `ssh is /usr/bin/ssh` and `alias ssh` returns empty